# To show hex color codes in batch

Tags: python, r, bash, colors, hex

I have some hex color code:

```
#ff9b9b
#ff5656
#ff0202
#ad0000
#871515
```

and I want to show the corresponding colors at the same time as a palette to conveniently choose the ones I want.

Is there any recommended online tools or we can do it in command line?
There are tools can show only one color at the same time, but I want to show several colors at once.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want python code to that you could use [colored](https://pypi.org/project/colored/), here's example where you choose font color and background color.

```
from colored import fg, bg, attr

color = fg('#C0C0C0') + bg('#00005f') # create font and background color
res = attr('reset') # adding that to string that we print reset current colors

print(color + "Hello World !!!" + res)
```